# How to modify amplitude, frequency and bandwidth values in python

Tags: python, interface, equalizer

As you can see in the imagen, I want to do just the interface you're looking at. (FL studio parametric eq 2)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3QQoq.jpg)

I want to modify a graph with 15 bands, move the frequency peak, change the amplitude values and modify de bandwith.

I saw some videos and answears here but I didn't found a tip or a similar project.

I'm new un python developing, I think this project is easy and I can understand some code but I can't do it by myself yet.

I know I could use matplotlib for the plot and sliders, also numpy.

I will really appreciate if somebody could give me a guide.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a modern version of FL Studio, there is an included Python API which allows you to access plugin parameters through the plugins module.

Use [`plugins.setParamValue()`](https://miguelguthridge.github.io/FL-Studio-API-Docs/docs/plugins.html#setParamValue) to set these parameters as required. It requires a `value` between `0` and `1`, a parameter index, and the mixer track number and slot index on the mixer track. You can get the parameter index by looking within the plugin properties in the browser.

Keep in mind that you can't add more bands to the stock parameteric EQ plugin though.